# iPad: creating a custom UISplitViewController

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I've been playing around with UISplitViewController for a while, but it's not customizable enough for my needs, so I was thinking I could create my own custom UISplitViewController, and what it would take to do so. Is it just a matter of creating 2 view controllers next to each other, with the master view keeping a reference to the detail view, and handling rotations properly (to show and hide the popover), or is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at Matt Legend Gemmell's custom splitview controller that was made last year for some pointers:

https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController